# Form resetting when HTML content added through jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a block of HTML that contains two different forms, one form is for a Group to fill out, the other is for an Individual to fill out. The first (and initially only) question a user can answer is a dropdown to select if they are filling out this form as a Group or Individual:

```html
<div class="pre-form">
    <label for="participant-type">Group or Individual?</label>
    <select name="participant-type" id="participant-type">
        <option value="participant-type-quesiton">Choose a performance type</option>
        <option value="individual-performer">Individual</option>
        <option value="group-performers">Group</option>
    </select>
</div>

<form class="hide form">
    <div class="form first individual">
        *individual form inputs*
    </div>

    <div class="form first group">
        *group form inputs*
    </div>
    <div class="add-participant-button">
       <button class="add-participant">Click to Add Another Participant</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

There is a button at the end of the Group form that allows a user to add additional participants. This is accomplished through jQuery by creating another 'performer-details' div and appending it to the 'performer-container' div.

relevant HTML:

```html
<div class="performer-container">
    <div class="performer-details">
        <div class="performer-title-container">
            <span class="title">Performer Details</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fields">
            <div class="input-field">
                <label>Performer First Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter performer's first name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label>Performer Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter performer's last name">
            </div>

            <div class="input-field number">
                <label>Performer Age</label>
                <input type="number" id="performer-age"></input>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <label>Performer Gender</label>
                <select name="performer-gender">
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <label>Performer Grade</label>
                <select name="performer-grade">
                    <option value="elementary">Elementary School</option>
                    <option value="middle">Middle School</option>
                    <option value="high">High School</option>
                    <option value="high">College</option>
                    <option value="na">N/A</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <label>Performer Class</label>
                <select name="performer-class">
                    <option value="dance">Dance</option>
                    <option value="guitar">Guitar</option>
                    <option value="guitarron">Guitarron</option>
                    <option value="harp">Harp</option>
                    <option value="trumpet">Trumpet</option>
                    <option value="vihuela">Vihuela</option>
                    <option value="violin">Violin</option>
                    <option value="voice">Voice</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <label>Performer Level</label>
                <select name="performer-level">
                    <option value="i">I</option>
                    <option value="ii">II</option>
                    <option value="master-voice">Master (Voice)</option>
                    <option value="master-non-voice">Master (Non-Voice)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery logic:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#participant-type").on("change", function () {
    if (this.value === "individual-performer") {
      $(".form").removeClass("hide");
      $(".group").hide();
      $(".individual").show();
    } else {
      $(".form").removeClass("hide");
      $(".group").show();
      $(".individual").hide();
    }
  });

  $(".add-participant").click(function () {
    const participantHtml = $(".performer-details").html();
    $(".performer-container").append(participantHtml);
  });
});
```

Whenever I click on the "add-participant" button however it simply resets my form back to the beginning "pre-form" single question of Group or Individual.

I have tried changing the on event in jQuery as well as using .html() to create the entire 'performer-container'.

My expectation is that I can click on the button and an additional group of the relevant participant fields will be created.

Comment: Two issues... 1) Your button is submitting the form. Use `type="button"` 2) `.html()` returns the contents, not the outer element. Use `.clone()` instead